# change button color when clicked and change others back to original

Tags: html, button, colors, back

I have a buttonbar with 11 buttons that causes page jumps in a page displayed in an iframe.

I want these buttons to change color when clicked, so they indicate which page is being displayed.

That´s easy. But here is the problem:

Say you click on button 4 - page jump occurs, page 4 is displayed, button 4 goes purple, everything´s fine.

But if you then click on page 7, page 7 is displayed, button 7 goes purple, but button 4 is still purple, does NOT go back to original color (grey).

**That´s what I need, a script that changes a button´s color to purple when it´s clicked, but also changes its color back to grey when another one IN THE BUTTONBAR is clicked.**

Here´s the button code:

`<div id="btn1" title="página 1" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height:25px; width: 25px; border: 0px ridge white; background-color: transparent; padding: 0px; text-align: center; font-size:10px; font-weight: bold; font-family: arial; olor: white; z-index:10100;`

`<input type=button name="1" value="1" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; font-size: 11px; text-align: left; background-color: "eeeeee"; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;"
onclick="this.style.cursor='hand', this.style.backgroundColor='purple'; this.style.color='white'; document.getElementById('licao').src='lesson1/l1d.htm#l1pg1'"
/>
</div>`

Had to leave some of the brackets out or code wouldn´t appear here...

So you see onclick the button changes color, but how do I make the OTHER buttons revert to their original color? There are 11 other buttons (for 11 pages) each makes a pagejump.

Thank you very very much for your help.

Leonardo.

Comment: May I ask why you use `<input type="button">` instead of `<button type="button">TEXT</button>` or just `<a>`as is the usual for navigation elements? Also, it is also preferred not to mix inline javascript to your HTML, and inline CSS is a real no-go (with exception for tables for example).

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery this is supereasy to do. You just need to include the jquery library and replace the $('a') with your html tag or class (notation with a . prefixing your class, like in CSS).

http://jsbin.com/apitih/2/edit

Code for reference:

The HTML:

```
<body>
  <a href="#">Page 1</a>
  <a href="#">Page 2</a>
  <a href="#">Page 3</a>
  <a href="#">Page 4</a>
  <a href="#">Page 5</a>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```css
a {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

The jQuery

```js
var links = $('a');
links.click(function() {
  links.css('background-color', 'grey');
  $(this).css('background-color', 'purple');
});
```